# Convert line parametrization into two equations

Tags: manifolds, systems-of-equations, parametric

Consider the following parametrization on $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$g(t) = (t^2,t\cos(t),t\sin(t))$$

This is a line, and as such can be characterized by two equations. I already found the first one to be

$$y^2 + z^2 = x$$

What would the second equation be?

Comment: It is NOT a line. It's a curve.

Comment: Isn't there only one curve? How can one curve have two equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{z}{y}=\tan t=\tan(\sqrt x).
$$